# Understanding HTML meta charset

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

Below is the sample HTML I have written to understand about `meta charset` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="ANSI" /> 
</head>
<body>
如
</body>
</html>
```

The BODY tag of this HTML contains chinese character.

Because chareset is set to "ANSI" , I was expecting that the chinese character will not be displayed in the browser, instead some junk character will get displayed.

I would like to know why chinese character is getting displayed correctly, even though charset is "ANSI" instead of UTF-8.

Comment: The server might send a `Content-Type` header with a specific encoding set. In that case, the encoding in the HTTP header will overwrite the meta charset value. If you open that HTML file (saved as UTF-8) without server headers, then the character should be broken.

Comment: It is OS dependent, in linux displays correctly without charset..... but windows 7 will not support.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ANSI" is not a [valid value](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) for `charset`.

A browser may also ignore the `<meta>` tag if:

- the HTTP `Content-Type` header tells it otherwise;
- there is a BOM at the beginning of the HTML; or
- the browser does not think the page is in the named charset (see [this process](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#encoding-sniffing-algorithm) for determining a page's character encoding).

Comment: how other regional language works in website?, how utf-8 supports for other languages? how this stuff works?, if there is any conversion from regional lang to utf, how it converted?

Comment: Is operating system contains all registered language packs?

Comment: In linux supports other language without charset....but windows 7 shows junk charecter. how it is?